# Nest Label inside Html5 button tag

Tags: html

```
<button class="myClass">
<label style="width:500px">This is sample 1</label>
<img class="btnImg" src="images/list_item_arrow.png"/>
</button>
.myClass
{
opacity:0.3;
color:#30F;
height:50px;
width:90%;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration:blink;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
 }
```

Label doesn't take width, tht is provided.
the requirement is: if button take some width in % or px, we can display image at right end.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Its label for a button so I don't think giving width will be useful. You can add *text-align:left;* to the class ".myClass" and give *margin-left* to the image, this way you can place your image wherever you want on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Labels don't belong inside controls. They are intended to label the control. If it's in the control, there is no need to indicate that it is a label,

To answer the question at hand, it is likely not changing in width because labels typically have a default `display` property of `inline`. You probably want `block` or `inline-block`.